# How can I make a "username and password" type search on a SQL server?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to search a table (programmatically, in C#) hosted on a free SQL hosting site (www.000webhost.com) to search the table for a username and compare it to the "password" string stored alongside the username. As I have never dealt with C# SQL connections before, I have no clue how to do this.

`{
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;" + "password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX;server=databases-auth.000webhost.com;" +
"Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; " + "connection timeout=30");
}`

The "username" would be typed in by the user it TextBox1, while the "password" would be in TextBox2. Any help with the code or links to examples/websites I would be able to use would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nooo... don't store raw passwords, always hash them...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, that's the later plan.

Comment: What framework are you using? ASP.NET? MVC? Both come with authentication correctly-implemented already built in. Don't reinvent wheels, especially if the one you built is triangular.

Comment: If you don't do it the right way now when are you ever going to go back and do it right? The answer....you won't. Do it right instead of right now or you will regret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would suggest is not to send passwords in raw format. At least try to hash them and save them in hashed form. When you want to make a query using passwords, just send the hashed string.

For hashing, you can use a "one-way" encryption format, like say MD5 or SHA-256. You can find these in System.Security.Cryptography.

Then, never concatenate strings to construct the query. Instead use parameterized commands, that way you will have a level of security. Take a look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) about parameterized commands

Finally, if you need more than 1 column to be returned, use the DataReader. If you only need 1 column to be returned, use the ExecuteScalar function, which returns a single value. In [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), you will find information about how to use ExecuteScalar.

Comment: Thank you - it's working as intended now and I've used System Cryptography to has them. Kudos to you.

Answer (score -2):

```
public String auth(String u, String p)
{

string recuperatedData = "";

        //Create Connection
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DRACARYS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI");

        //SQL Command
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT password FROM dbo.databasename WHERE username = '" + u +"'"  , conn); 

        //Open connection
        conn.Open();

        //To read from SQL Server
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            recuperatedData = dr["password"].ToString();
        }

        //Close Connections
        dr.Close();

        if (recuperatedData == p)
        {
             //return flag value to shos you've logged in to a different function with post log in functionalities
        } 
}
```

Comment: What if my username is `' OR ''='`

Comment: Then add an OR comment in the same syntax format as above. Just like SQL syntaxes. This is code from a personal project which would give the person asking the question the ideas they need to proceed with the project. Additions can always be made based on necessities once the initial conceptual issues are resolved.

Comment: @SoumyajyotiBhattacharya I think that DourHighArch is referring to a username that is literally `' OR ''='`. The point being made, is that your query is open to SQL injections. If I tried to login with a username of `' OR ''='`, then your SQL would be: `SELECT password FROM dbo.databasename WHERE username = '' OR ''=''`, which result in every row being returned.